# Send MTOM encoded request from Postman to WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, postman, mtom

I am trying to create WCF service that can receive MTOM encoded messages. I do not have client that sends MTOM encoded messages, however I do have message example (that's why I am trying to use Postman).

**Request example:**

> Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";
>   boundary="uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5";
>   start="";
>   start-info="application/soap+xml;
>   action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""
>
> Payload: --uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5 Content-Type:
>   application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml;
>   action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary Content-ID:
>
> ...
>   --uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5--

**Postman:**
[image]
[image]

**Service contract**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResponseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    AcknowledgementType ResponseInputMessage(RegistryResponseType registryResponse);
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpMtomBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MySvc.ResponseService">
    <endpoint address="ResponseService.svc" contract="MySvc.IResponseService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpMtomBinding"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

WSDL (http://localhost:50809/ResponseService.svc?wsdl) displays:

```
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:50809/ResponseService.svc/ResponseService.svc"/>
```

When I send a request to `http://localhost:50809/ResponseService.svc/ResponseService.svc` Postman says `Could not get any response`. If I send a request to `http://localhost:50809/ResponseService.svc` is returns `404`.

Please suggest what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Why **MTOM**?

The preferred approach to send large binary messages in WCF is to use MTOM message encoding. MTOM is an interoperable standard and stands for Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism. MTOM does not base64 encode data. This also means, the additional processing overhead to base64 encode and decode data is removed. Hence, MTOM can significantly improve the overall message transfer performance.

Set messageEncoding="Mtom" in both the WCF service and the client if possible.

```
 <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpMtomBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="700000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="700000"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

Content Type of MTOM will be is **multipart/related**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already have Mtom in my service. Maybe I just have incorrect configuration in postman? Are you suggesting to leave content type only `multipart/related`, but where should `type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5"; start=""; start-info="application/soap+xml; action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""` go? Please check my question I updated it to include postman screenshots.

Comment: This link might help you .https://coderanch.com/t/637546/certification/MTOM-message-Header-parameters.You use mtom for binary things ,is your input mime type is text then why MTOM?

Comment: Thanks, based on this link it looks like request from Postman is right. Probably the problem is in WCF service. Maybe you have any idea what could be wrong with WCF service? Maybe I am missing some config option..

Comment: Tracing and message logging can tell you more about this.If you had implemented fault exception it could have helped more.